# positioning a sprite in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, sprite

I've got a problem to draw a sprite to my project.

I have a map (960x900) divided into tiles (64x64).

As you can see in the picture, when i click on the bottom left corner of the purple square, the position is (0;0), and when I click on the top right corner of purple square, the position is (36;47)

The problem is that the picture of the purple square has a size of 32x32, and when I draw this picture with libgdx on the screen, the size doesn't match.

[image: the problem is the purple gem]

Another example: the square with black border has a size of 64x64. So if I draw the purple square in front of the black, the purple should be the half (in height and in width) of the black, no?

Does anyone know why libgdx resizes the purple square?

`Sprite sprite = new Sprite(new Texture("assets/purpleSquare.png"));`

i draw it in a method

```
public void render(SpriteBatch batch) {
    batch.draw(sprite, 0, 0);
}
```

I don't know why the picture is resized by libgdx.. I have also tried to do

```
batch.draw(sprite, 0, 0, width, heigth);
```

To precise the sprite's size but it doesn't work too..

Comment: Can you post some code? How do you get the texture regions, how do you draw it, etc..?

Answer (score 3):

The size on screen bears no direct relation to the size of the original image. When you draw a sprite you provide the SpriteBatch with a position, width, and height in **world coordinates**. The sprite will be stretched to fit these world coordinates, regardless of the original image size.

When you click the screen, you are clicking in **screen coordinates**. The relation between screen and world coordinates is determined by the projection matrix that you use with the SpriteBatch. The projection matrix is typically controlled with a Camera or Viewport object, which you can use to convert between the two coordinate systems using the `project` and `unproject` methods.

Comment: Ok, but here i just want to draw the sprite into the (0;0) position, without giving width and heigth.

I initialize the SpriteBatch like that 

"private SpriteBatch batch;" and i just do a "batch.begin()", follow by the "render(SpriteBatch batch)" method and ending by "batch.end()"

I have to use a Camera ?

Comment: If you don't use a camera, SpriteBatch automatically instantiates with a projection matrix that translates 1 pixel to 1 world unit, but it won't respond automatically to screen rotations or window resizes. However, by default, Y is down in world coordinates, while Y is up in screen coordinates. If you don't provide a width and height when drawing a sprite, SpriteBatch uses the pixel dimensions of the original image (I'll correct that above) as the world size of the sprite. I suspect something is modifying your batch's projection matrix between drawing the grey square and the purple square.

Comment: Ok, you're right. I've add a OrthographicCamera and i set the position's camera. I've update the camera and set the SpriteBatch's projection and it works good !
Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score -1):

I'm happy to see that after many hours i found a solution, even if i know which is not correct.

I would like some help to understand the problem's origin.

With this parts of code :

```
public void update(float delta) {       
    batch.begin();

    drawBackground(); // Draw the background
    drawButton(); // Draw the play/pause button

    batch.end();

    drawMap(); // draw a tmx map made with tiled

    batch.begin();

    if(!world.isInitial()) {
        renderMonster(); // method which draw the monster
    }

    renderTower(); // method which draw the tower's level

    batch.end();
}
```

1. I don't understand why i have to do "batch.begin()" and "batch.end()" twice.
2. I dont' understant why with this code, the purple square is resized.

**With this code :**

```
public void update(float delta) {       
    batch.begin();

    drawBackground();
    drawButton();

    batch.end();

    drawMap();

    ------->sb = new SpriteBatch();

    sb.begin();

    if(!world.isInitial()) {
        renderMonster();
    }

    renderTower();

    sb.end();
}
```

this line that i add fix the bug with the purple square. If i work with two SpriteBatch (because with one, if i reinitialize SpriteBatch in update method, my pause/play button diseapper) and i initialise the second (SpriteBatch sb) in the update method.

It is correct to initialise a SpriteBatch every time i'm passing on the update method ? There's no method with a SpriteBatch to avoid this problem ?

Comment: It is really BAD to create the spritebatch on every draw - you create a new object 60 times per second, it is really heavy.
The end() call causes a batch to flush and invoke the OpenGL draw call which is not that heavy but better avoid it - you want a good performance on the crappy phones.
You should be aware that every action in the update() method is called many many times (around 60 times per second) and could bring you lag.

Comment: This is not how SE works, don't mistake this site for a forum. You can enter (and edit) one single question. Every "post" below should be a answer.

Comment: Yasen Bagalev : I know that it's incorrect, but why when i initialize the SpriteBatch every time i update the screen, pictures aren't resized and when i just call batch.begin() and batch.end() pictures are resized ?

There is something better to do for avoid this problem ?

Comment: We can't tell without seeing more of your original code. But probably your original Sprite batch's projection matrix was modified while all the new ones are getting the default screen sized one. Note that you must call dispose on a Sprite batch before its reference is lost or there will be a memory leak. And of course, you should be reusing a single Sprite batch for the whole app.